# How to change Telerik's Rich Text Editor background?

Tags: telerik, sitecore, rich-text-editor

I have a white text in Rich Text Editor and background is white as well. How can I change background in editor, so user will be able to see text. Here is screenshot how it looks like at the moment:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is “Editor.css” file in “..\website\sitecore\shell\controls\Rich Text Editor” folder. 
I added following css style there:

```
body {
  background-color:black;
}
```

And it works as expected.